# C# receive data from Arduino WI-FI

Tags: c#, arduino, wifi, arduino-uno, networkstream

I have a C# program to receive data from Arduino sensors (gps, roll, pitch...). Everything is working fine when using serial connection (COM/USB). I connected a WIFI module to the Arduino and send/receive using socket. Can I know how to continuous read/receive the data through wifi from the Arduino? (I know the sending part but don't know the receiving part). I need help for translating the receiving part(serialport) to WIFI NetworkStream.

This is part of my C# winform code

```
int HostPort = 4998;
string Host = "192.168.0.2";
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcpClient = new  System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  byte[] M1bytesToSend = new byte[1] { 0xFF };
  NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
  networkStream.Write(M1bytesToSend, 0, M1bytesToSend.Length);
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  tcpClient.Connect(Host, HostPort);
}
```

The receive part C# for serialport1:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
  Thread.Sleep(50);
  int bytes = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
  string data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
  Char delimiter = '*';
  String[] substrings = data.Split(delimiter);
  if ((bytesRx > 25) & (bytesRx < 40)) {
    //receive 2nd part Arduino code and do something
  }
  if ((bytesRx > 15) & (bytesRx < 25)) {
    //receive 1st part arduino code and do something
  }
}
```

This is my Arduino code that will continuously send data to Winform.

```
Serial.print("*"); // 1st part
ypr[1]=(ypr[1] * 180/M_PI)+90;
Serial.print(ypr[1]);
Serial.print("*");
ypr[2]=(ypr[2] * 180/M_PI)+90;
Serial.print(ypr[2]);
Serial.print("*");
Serial.print(ypr[0] * 180/M_PI);//yaw
Serial.print("*");
delay(50);
Serial.print("*"); //second part
Serial.print(headingDegrees);
Serial.print("*");
Serial.print(b,6);
Serial.print("*");
Serial.print(c,6);
Serial.print("*");
```